# Deep linking using react navigation and exponent

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I've been searching over the internet on using deep linking using react navigation and exponent (react native). My scenario is when I click a link in the email my react native app will be open and navigate to a specific scene/route.

Thanks!

Comment: Have u gone through the official docs - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/linking

Comment: I'm using exponent that's why I cannot the xcode and the android project

Comment: oh kk, I think u cannot handle deep links without changing some lines in native code, so u must probably eject from expo.

Comment: Maybe I do not really understand, what you mean by a deeplink, but would a Stacknavigator not solve your problem? You can also disable the back button in it, if you do not want to see that.